# Execute 1000 tasks with 10 worker threads

Tags: php, pthreads, threadpool

I have 1000 tasks and I'd like to use pthreads with 10 running workers to process these tasks.
Since PHP doesn't have multithreading of its own I thought of using pthreads.

I suppose the best way to do this is using the pthreads `Pool`. Now I wonder how I could do this code-wise. I don't have any experience using pthreads and all Pool examples I found on the web didn't work on my server. Particularly those on the pthreads [Github page](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/blob/master/examples/Pooling.php) throw this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Collectable' not found

Comment: Class not found, is there any other information you need? Check if the class exists and is included

Comment: I just said this as a sidenote, I wanted to see some code that could solve my problem, help me find the right direction.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Questions asking for tools, examples and such are considered off topic here on StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

For the error

```
    Fatal error: Class 'Collectable' not found
```

I had the same problem with pecl, if you use the github repo it's fine here how to:

```
    $ git clone https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads lib-pthreads
    $ phpize
    $ ./configure
    $ make
```

Comment: This is the reason for the fatal error, you will be able to run examples when you have the latest source. A release is coming, there is WIP on a couple of (unrelated, pretty edge case) issues.

Answer (score -2):

So I don't know what you want. You want to know what causes error (without giving any details), or how you should write a code in... general? Error looks like You just haven't included Class 'Collectable'.

Comment: No, Actually I need an example for pthreads pool how to execute 1000 tasks with 10 threads.